# Problema con la ejecución de comandos python

Tags: python, django, cmd

El simbolo del sistema no me reconoce los comandos python como "python manage.py runserver" tampoco el de "python" incluso al poner solo "python" habre el store de microsoft cabe decir que funcionaba con normalidad el dia anterior.
Tambien cree un entorno virtual pero es el mismo.
Tambien reinicio la pc

Comment: verifica que las variables de entorno estén en tu sistema, si un día anterior podías ejecutar los comando es probable que sea otra cosa, pero es un buen inicio para que nos comentes, ya que con esa información que nos pones es dificil saber el problema

Comment: gracias por contestar, si revise las variables de entorno estaban bien despues como de 30 min funciono otra vez sin hacer literal nada